# What does the energy level referred to as ${}^3P_2$ refer to?

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy

I am looking at a video about the latest nuclear-based quantum computer and it refers to energy levels by a notation I cannot decipher: for example $^3P_2$

$P$ refers to orbital angular momentum $\ell=1$, I reckon, and perhaps the $2$ is the total angular momentum $j=\ell+s$, but what the heck does the $3$ refer to?

Comment: It's a [term symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol).

Comment: The 3 indicates a spin triplet, so spin s=1.

Comment: So s is the total angular momentum, from the electron and the nucleus together?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this notation is known as a [term symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol). You are mostly correct in your interpretation. In general, the notation goes
$$
^{2S+1}L_J,
$$
where $J$ is the total angular momentum, $L$ is the total orbital angular momentum (normally expressed in [spectroscopic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopic_notation), so $L=0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ are expressed as $S$, $P$, $D$, $F$, $G$, $H$, ...), and the initial superscript is known as the spin multiplicity, given by $2S+1$, where $S$ is the total spin angular momentum.

It is important to note that when dealing with term symbols and other electronic-structure notation, lower-case symbols are associated with single-electron quantities and upper-case symbols are associated with multi-electron quantities. Thus, the use of $P$ implies a multi-electron state, so you would use $L$ instead of $\ell$ and $J$ instead of $j$.

And finally, it is important to note that, in general, $J$ need not coincide with $L+S$. The as an identity between vector operators, $\vec J = \vec L + \vec S$ does hold, but that does not mean that the corresponding quantum numbers are additive. For more details, see the section on your textbook on the addition of angular momenta in QM.